# Reactive Spring Query Parameters

Tags: spring-boot, reactive, handlers, query-string

My Spring Reactive Web API should be able to filter based on query parameters but I'm struggling to get this right.

```
GET /v1/address?type=business
```

Should return all addresses of type 'business' in the system (just an example since I'm not posting the actual requirements). If the parameter is absent then just return all addresses.

```
[
  { "id" : 1, "type" : "business", "street" : "..."},
  { "id" : 2, "type" : "business", "street" : "..."},
  ...
}
```

I'm using Router functions to map the request:

```
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(AddressHandler handler) {
    return route(GET("/v1/address"), handler::getAddresses);
}
```

But I'm struggling to determine how to check for the parameter and, if it isn't present, to return all addresses.

```
class AddressHandler {
    Mono<ServerResponse> getAddressesFilteredOrNot(ServerRequest request) {
        Optional<String> addressType = request.getQueryParam("type");

        ...
    }
}
```

Now the Optional.ifPresent() isn't going to work, I can't return from the method:

```
class AddressHandler {
    Mono<ServerResponse> getAddressesFilteredOrNot(ServerRequest request) {
        Optional<String> addressType = request.getQueryParam("type");

        // invalid
        addressType.ifPresent(addrType -> {
            return ServerResponse.ok()
                .body(this.service.getAddressByType(addrType),
                   Address.class);
    });
}
```

Also I can't switchIfEmpty() on the parameter since it throws a NullPointerException:

```
class AddressHandler {
    Mono<ServerResponse> getAddressesFilteredOrNot(ServerRequest request) {
        Optional<String> addressType = request.getQueryParam("type");

        // also invalid
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(addressType.orElse(""))
               .flatMap(addrType -> ServerResponse.ok().body(this.service.getAddressByType(addrType), Address.class)
               .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.ok().body(this.service.getAllAddresses(), Address.class));
    });
}
```

What's the flow to use query parameters if they are present and fall back on the getAllAddresses() method? Is it actually possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `orElse()` or `orElseGet()` functionality of `Optional` to invoke an alternative method. For example:

```java
request
    .getQueryParam("type")
    .map(type -> service.getAddressByType(type))
    .orElseGet(() -> service.getAllAddresses());
```

In this case, `orElseGet()` makes more sense, because it's lazily invoked. Be aware though that both methods should have the same return type, so probably `Flux<Address>`.

Comment: Thanks for that g00glen00b, I have a feeling I'm approaching this from the wrong angle. Ideally the request parameters need to become a first class citizen in this approach, so rather than having a method that calls:   service.findAll() . I should instead be passing the filter parameters to the service such as Flux<Address> findAll(filterParams) {}. I'm going to acce[t this since you answered the question on the Optional, but I'll come back with a better way to approach this problem. :)

Comment: Nope I was able to put your answer into context and it makes sense - I just decorated it with a bit of error handling. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, but with a query param of an **array** type:

```
GET /v1/address?type=foo&type=bar&type=baz
```

I was too dumb to spend time on this, while the solution was right there:

```
request.queryParams()["type"] ?: listOf()
```