# Reactive Spring Many Query Parameters

Tags: handler, spring-webflux, reactive, query-string

Tell me how to work with ServerRequest. If I need to get N parameters.

I find simple example with 1 parameter.
[Reactive Spring Query Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043664/reactive-spring-query-parameters)

```
request
    .getQueryParam("type")
    .map(type -> service.getAddressByType(type))
    .orElseGet(() -> service.getAllAddresses());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getQueryParams`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/ServerRequest.html#queryParams-java.lang.String-) to get N parameters as a map.

`getQueryParams()` returns `MultiValueMap`, so you can handle query params as a map.

Let me make small example like your code block.

```
val queryParamsMap = request.queryParams() 
queryParamsMap["type"]?.let { type -> service.getAddressByType(type) } ?: let { service.getAllAddresses() }
```

Comment: Can you give small example??